# React Native: How to change BackgroundColor using TouchableOpacity onPress

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am stuck with changing Backgorund color while i am pressing , it is changing but not for the whole screen, it has its limits, can someone help me with this???
I am stuck with changing Backgorund color while i am pressing , it is changing but not for the whole screen, it has its limits, can someone help me with this???
I am stuck with changing Backgorund color while i am pressing , it is changing but not for the whole screen, it has its limits, can someone help me with this???
[image]

here is my code , I used even flex: 1, how can i solve this, any help)),  :

```
export default Boom=()=>{

    [color, setColor] = useState('white');
    return (

     <View style = {styles.container}>
     
        <TouchableOpacity onPress = {()=> setColor('blue')} style= {{backgroundColor: color,}} >
          <Text style={{
            color: 'white',
            padding: 16,
            marginTop: 16,
            borderColor: '#bbb',
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderStyle: 'dashed',
            borderRadius: 10,
            backgroundColor: 'blue' }}>Blue</Text>

        </TouchableOpacity >



        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setColor('red')} style={{ backgroundColor: color, }}>

          <Text style={{
            color: 'white',
            padding: 16,
            marginTop: 16,
            borderColor: '#bbb',
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderStyle: 'dashed',
            borderRadius: 10 ,
            backgroundColor: 'red'}}>Red</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>


        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setColor('black')} style={{ backgroundColor: color }}>

          <Text style={{
            color : 'white',
            padding: 16,
            marginTop: 16,
            borderColor: '#bbb',
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderStyle: 'dashed',
            borderRadius: 10 ,
            backgroundColor : 'black' }} >Black</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
</View>
    );




}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',}
  })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
<View style = {{
  flex: 1,
  justifyContent: 'center',
  alignItems: 'center',
  backgroundColor: color
}} >

...
</View>
```

Comment: But here i will not use StyleSheet.create yes? what if i want to use this, how can i solve this problem?